# Dynamic Attribute Binding + Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types

Tags: entity-framework, attributes

I'm struggeling figuring the proper way of Solving "Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types". The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data"  Entity Framework

I have an entity like.

```
public partial class Document
{
     DocumentId {get; set;}
     DocumentName{get; set;}
}

public class SpecialDocument
{
     DocumentId {get; set;}  --> this is actually a foreign key from Document  
                                 at the same time it is also the primary key 
     SpecialDocumentName {get; set;}
}
```

I found a solution like adding a ForeignKey attribute on the property.

```
public partial class SpecialDocument
{
      [ForeignKey("Document")]
      DocumentId {get; set;)
      SpecialDocumentName {get; set;}
}
```

however the problem is the class is autogenerated, whenever i update the edmx file the SpecialDocument is overwritten so now i need to re-add the ForeginKey attribute.

Is there something I can do to the separate partial class for the SpecialDocument or Dnyaminc Attribute Attachment to the Property? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to work with Inheritance, and so `DocumentId` won't be treated as a foreign key with Entity Framework. Try to change your model around to use inheritance and it should solve your problem, like so.

```
public partial class Document
{
     DocumentId {get; set;}
     DocumentName{get; set;}
}

public class SpecialDocument : Document
{
     SpecialDocumentName {get; set;}
}
```

By removing the `DocumentId` property from `SpecialDocument` and making it inherit from `Document`, Entity Framework will know that when you create a new `SpecialDocument` it will first create a standard `Document` and then in the `SpecialDocument` table it will add the properties as required.

Comment: Nope, I'm not trying to accomplish inheritance here. This Entities are just autogenerated by the edmx. and It just happened that the DocumentId is both the Primary Key for both class, and the DocumentId from SpecialDocument is a foreignkey from DocumentId(Document)

Comment: What pattern would you consider it? One solution would be to switch to code first, or change your `tt` template to reflect this. But what you're doing, if not inheritance is not a standard practice, hence why you're getting strange behaviour.

Comment: Yes changing the tt template is on my track now to reflect the attribute. i'm still looking at it how to accomplish it in the tt file. Thanks!